# IF condition is always false in this case

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to reduce opacity with JavaScript. But the problem is that 'if' condition is always false therefor the opacity is getting 0. Please can anyone explain why this is happening and the correct solution.

```
var opacity = 1;
var decrement = 0.01;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame(){
    if (opacity == 0.4) //It is always false..
    {
        clearInterval(id);//Not able to clear Interval
    }
    else
    {
        opacity = opacity-decrement;
        document.getElementsByClassName('menu_bar')[0].style.backgroundColor='rgba(66,64,61,'+opacity+')';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that these are fractions represented as floating point numbers, so exact equality is not guaranteed. See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @B001ᛦ `opacity = opacity-decrement;`

Comment: The problem is floating point maths.  Change the if statement to `if (opacity <= 0.4)` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 See my comment above yours.

Comment: @Lucif Incidentally, unless you have a specific reason for doing this with Javscript, you can achieve the exact same results with pure CSS (and no faffing around with error prone maths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity == 0.4` in your code, try using `opacity < 0.5` or `opacity <= 0.4` as fractions are not very reliable in javascript.

Try running `1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1` (The math that happens before your `== 0.4` check should return true) in your console to see what I mean.

Comment: It's not just Javascript, it's pretty much every programming language since the invention of "floating point" representation.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(Math.abs(opacity - 0.4) < 0.01) {
```

[Floating point math is "broken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript), therefore you have to be fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the [floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) is broke.

A simple fix is to use integers and divide the end result with 100.

That will also avoid any extra `Math.abs`, or calc, at every interval.

Stack snippet

```js
var opacity = 100;
var decrement = 1;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

function frame() {
  if (opacity == 40)
  {
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {
    opacity = opacity - decrement;
    //document.getElementsByClassName('menu_bar')[0].style.backgroundColor='rgba(66,64,61,'+opacity/100+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor='rgba(66,64,61,'+opacity/100+')';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use opacity.toFixed(2) to restrict the decimal digits to 2, this will sole the issue
```

```js
var opacity = 1;
var decrement = 0.01;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame(){
    if (opacity.toFixed(2) == 0.40) //It is always false..
    {
        console.log("Cleared");
        clearInterval(id);//Not able to clear Interval
    }
    else
    {
        opacity = opacity-decrement;
       // document.getElementsByClassName('menu_bar')[0].style.backgroundColor='rgba(66,64,61,'+opacity+')';
    }
}
```